# remove specific legend apache poi excel graph XDDFChartLegend

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-charts

i am using apache poi 5.0.0 version
i have generated a graph in excel using the data and i am able to see the legends in the bottom of the graph. There are six legends shown. Now i want to remove two specific legends without removing them from the graph.

[image]

There seems to be no functions available in XDDFChartLegend which really works. say for example

```
XDDFChartLegend  legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
legend.getEntries().remove(4);
```

doesnt work

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chart legend entry cannot be removed. It only can be marked deleted, so it will not be shown.

[XDDFLegendEntry](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFLegendEntry.html) provides method `setDelete` to do so. But the problem is how to get the `XDDFLegendEntry`.

`XDDFChart.getOrAddLegend` only adds an empty legend marker which uses defaults for showing the legend. There are no legend entries by default as those only are needed to set special properties which are not default. So we would need someting like `XDDFChartLegend.getOrAddLegendEntry` to get or add a legend entry. This does not exist until now.

Following method gets or adds a legend entry to a given `XDDFChartLegend` for a given index.

```
 XDDFLegendEntry getOrAddLegendEntry(XDDFChartLegend legend, long index) {
  XDDFLegendEntry legendEntry = null;
  for (XDDFLegendEntry storedLegendEntry : legend.getEntries()) {
   if (storedLegendEntry.getIndex() == index) {
    legendEntry = storedLegendEntry;
    break;
   }   
  }
  if (legendEntry == null) {
   legendEntry = legend.addEntry();
   legendEntry.setIndex(index); 
  }
  return legendEntry;
 }
```

Note, I do not use [XDDFChartLegend.getEntry](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartLegend.html#getEntry-int-) as this returns the entry at **position** `index` rather than the entry having the index `index`. But we need the entry having the index `index`. So I loop over all entries and do check whether there is one having the index already.

Usage to mark legend entry as deleted could be as so:

```
...
   XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
   //...
   XDDFLegendEntry legendEntry = getOrAddLegendEntry(legend, 4);
   legendEntry.setDelete(true);
...
```

Comment: Perfect answer!!

Comment: @Kannan Sundararaj: Please note my edit.