# Create oooxml chart. with org.apache.poi

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi, openxml

I'm currently making an Excel chart using org.apache.poi and oooxml library. I developed the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUIoG.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYBT5.jpg)

```
XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 20, 57);

XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart();
CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();

//여기까지는 똑같음

//the first bar chart
CTBarChart ctBarChart = ctPlotArea.addNewBarChart();
CTBoolean ctBoolean = ctBarChart.addNewVaryColors();
ctBoolean.setVal(true);
ctBarChart.addNewBarDir().setVal(STBarDir.COL);

//the first chart series
CTBarSer ctBarSer = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
CTSerTx ctSerTx = ctBarSer.addNewTx();
CTStrRef ctStrRef = ctSerTx.addNewStrRef();
ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$10");
ctBarSer.addNewIdx().setVal(0);
CTAxDataSource ctAxDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewCat();
ctStrRef = ctAxDataSource.addNewStrRef();
ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$A$11:$A$34");
CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewVal();
CTNumRef ctNumRef = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumRef();
ctNumRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$11:$B$34");

//the second chart series
CTBarSer ctBarSer1 = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
CTSerTx ctSerTx1 = ctBarSer1.addNewTx();
CTStrRef ctStrRef1 = ctSerTx1.addNewStrRef();
ctStrRef1.setF("Sheet1!$C$10");
ctBarSer1.addNewIdx().setVal(1);
CTAxDataSource ctAxDataSource1 = ctBarSer1.addNewCat();
ctStrRef1 = ctAxDataSource1.addNewStrRef();
ctStrRef1.setF("Sheet1!$A$11:$A$34");
CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource1 = ctBarSer1.addNewVal();
CTNumRef ctNumRef1 = ctNumDataSource1.addNewNumRef();
ctNumRef1.setF("Sheet1!$C$11:$C$34");

// 3번째
CTBarSer ctBarSer2 = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
CTSerTx ctSerTx2 = ctBarSer2.addNewTx();
CTStrRef ctStrRef2 = ctSerTx2.addNewStrRef();
ctStrRef2.setF("Sheet1!$D$10");
ctBarSer2.addNewIdx().setVal(2);
CTAxDataSource ctAxDataSource2 = ctBarSer2.addNewCat();
ctStrRef2 = ctAxDataSource2.addNewStrRef();
ctStrRef2.setF("Sheet1!$A$11:$A$34");
CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource2 = ctBarSer2.addNewVal();
CTNumRef ctNumRef2 = ctNumDataSource2.addNewNumRef();
ctNumRef2.setF("Sheet1!$D$11:$D$34");

//at least the border lines in Libreoffice Calc ;-)
ctBarSer.addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[] {0,0,0});
ctBarSer1.addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[] {0,0,0});
ctBarSer2.addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[] {0,0,0});

ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); //cat axis 1 (lines)
ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //val axis 1 (left)
ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123458); //val axis 1 (right)
ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123459); //val axis 1 (right)

//cat axis 1
CTCatAx ctCatAx = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx();
ctCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
CTScaling ctScaling = ctCatAx.addNewScaling();
ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
ctCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
ctCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
ctCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
ctCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

//val axis 1 (left)
CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx();
ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
ctValAx.addNewCrosses().setVal(STCrosses.AUTO_ZERO); //this val axis crosses the cat axis at zero
ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);
```

As for the amount of "transmission= C cell", the unit is large, so I'm trying to make another value axis on the right, but I kept getting errors, so I asked. How can I create a valueaxis on the right, the number of "transmissions" based on the right, and the "user D cell , transfer count B cell" generates a chart based on the left?

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using?

Comment: im using version

org.apache.poi - poi - 4.1.0
org.apache.poi - poi-ooxml - 4.1.0

thank you

Comment: i don't have to use the 4.1.0 version. You can use the other version, so I have to solve this problem. If there's another way to make an Excel chart, please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `apache poi 4` on you should use the new `XDDF` classes to create charts. Playing around with the low level `CT*` classes is very complex and error prone.

Using line charts I have provided an example already here: [Second Line in an Apache-POI chart with seperate axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245147/second-line-in-an-apache-poi-chart-with-seperate-axis/63246879#63246879).

But using bar charts there is an additional problem to solve. If one bar chart series is on primary axis and another is on secondary axis, then the bars will overlap each other. This is because each of the series are oriented only on those series using the same axis. In other words the series on primary axis do not respect the series on the secondary axis when it comes to taking space on the chart. For line charts this is not a problem but for bar charts it is.

To solve this additional series having dummy data (all 0) can be used on both the axes. Those additional series lead to invisible bars (height 0) which also take space and so can be used to shift the visible bars.

The following complete example shows this. It is tested and works using `apache poi 4.1.2` and `apache poi 5.1.0`.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcelXDDFChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (XSSFWorkbook document = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
   XSSFSheet chartSheet = document.createSheet("chart");
   XSSFSheet dataSheet = document.createSheet("data");
        
   // create the data
   String[] categories = new String[] { "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9" };
   Double[] values1 = new Double[] { 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d };
   Double[] values2 = new Double[] { 200d, 300d, 400d, 500d, 600d, 700d, 800d, 900d, 1000d };
   int r = 0;
   for (String cat : categories) {
    dataSheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue(cat);
    dataSheet.getRow(r).createCell(1).setCellValue(values1[r]);
    dataSheet.getRow(r).createCell(2).setCellValue(values2[r]);
    r++;
   }

   // create the chart
   XSSFDrawing drawing = chartSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 22);
   XDDFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
   
   // create data sources
   int numOfPoints = categories.length;
   // dummy 0-values for the pad data source
   Double[] dummyValuesForPad = new Double[numOfPoints];
   for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++) {
    dummyValuesForPad[i] = 0d;  
   }
   XDDFDataSource<String> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 0, 0));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 1, 1));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 2, 2));
   // data source for the pad series
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> pad = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(dummyValuesForPad);

   // first bar chart
   XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
   leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
   leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);
   
   XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
   XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
   bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);
   
   XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData1);
   series.setTitle("Series 1", null);
   // additional pad series - takes space at right side for primary axis
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, pad);
   series.setTitle("pad", null);
   
   chart.plot(data);

   // second bar chart
   // bottom axis must be there but must not be visible
   bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   bottomAxis.setVisible(false);

   XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
   rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);
   rightAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

   // set correct cross axis
   bottomAxis.crossAxis(rightAxis);
   rightAxis.crossAxis(bottomAxis);

   data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
   bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
   bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);
   
   // additional pad series - takes space at left side for secondary axis
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, pad);
   series.setTitle("pad", null);
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData2);
   series.setTitle("Series 2", null);
 
   chart.plot(data);

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelXDDFChart.xlsx")) {
    document.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Above example works when Microsoft Excel is used to show the resulting `*.xlsx` file. But some other spreadsheet calculation applications are not able to use array literals (`{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`) as data source for chart series. So the more compatible solution will be using a unused cell range as datasource for the additional dummy series. For example use column `IV` for this as so:

```
...
   // dummy 0-values for the pad data source in column IV
   for (int r = 0; r < numOfPoints; r++) {
    XSSFRow row = dataSheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = dataSheet.createRow(r);
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(255);
    cell.setCellValue(0);
   }
   // data source for the pad series
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> pad = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 255, 255));
...
```

And also for compatibility reasons you should set colors for the bars as done in the `apache poi` example in `BarChart.java` which is available in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/usermodel/. Some other spreadsheet calculation applications will not automatically choose color if not given, as Excel does.

If you have more than one series in one of the bar chart, you need more pad series in the other bar chart which uses the other axis. The pad series are needed to shift the visible bar series and to determine the bar width of them. So if you have two visible bar series on the first chart which uses the left axis and one visible bar series on the second chart which uses the right axis, then you need one additional pad series as the last series in the first bar chart and you need two pad series as the first series in the second bar chart. In other words, you need as much pad series that both bar charts have the same count of series to have the same bar width in both. And the position of the invisible pad series determines how the visible bar series are shifted.

If you need a legend, then the pad series will disturb. So you need deleting them from the legend. In [remove specific legend apache poi excel graph XDDFChartLegend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460798/remove-specific-legend-apache-poi-excel-graph-xddfchartlegend/69463389#69463389) I have shown how to do that.

I will provide another complete example which shows all this:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcelXDDFChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (XSSFWorkbook document = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
   XSSFSheet chartSheet = document.createSheet("chart");
   XSSFSheet dataSheet = document.createSheet("data");
        
   // create the data
   String[] categories = new String[] { "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9" };
   Double[] values1 = new Double[] { 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d, 6d, 7d, 8d, 9d };
   Double[] values2 = new Double[] { 200d, 300d, 400d, 500d, 600d, 700d, 800d, 900d, 1000d };
   Double[] values3 = new Double[] { 4.5d, 4d, 3.5d, 3d, 2.5d, 2d, 1.5d, 1d, 0.5d };
   int r = 0;
   for (String cat : categories) {
    dataSheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue(cat);
    dataSheet.getRow(r).createCell(1).setCellValue(values1[r]);
    dataSheet.getRow(r).createCell(2).setCellValue(values2[r]);
    dataSheet.getRow(r).createCell(3).setCellValue(values3[r]);
    r++;
   }

   // create the chart
   XSSFDrawing drawing = chartSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 22);
   XDDFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      
   // create data sources
   int numOfPoints = categories.length;
   XDDFDataSource<String> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 0, 0));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 1, 1));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 2, 2));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesData3 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 3, 3));
   /*
   // dummy 0-values for the pad data source
   Double[] dummyValuesForPad = new Double[numOfPoints];
   for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++) {
    dummyValuesForPad[i] = 0d;  
   }
   */
   // data source for the pad series
   //XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> pad = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(dummyValuesForPad);
   //XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> pad = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(dummyValuesForPad, null);
   
   // dummy 0-values for the pad data source in column IV
   for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++) {
    XSSFRow row = dataSheet.getRow(i); if (row == null) row = dataSheet.createRow(i);
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(255);
    cell.setCellValue(0);
   }
   // data source for the pad series
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> pad = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, numOfPoints-1, 255, 255));

   // first bar chart
   XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
   leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
   leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);
   
   XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
   XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
   bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);
   
   XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData1);
   series.setTitle("Series 1", null);
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData3);
   series.setTitle("Series 3", null);
   // additional pad series - takes space at right side for primary axis
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, pad);
   series.setTitle("pad", null);
   
   chart.plot(data);
   
   // set bar colors
   solidFillSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.GREEN);
   solidFillSeries(data, 1, PresetColor.BLUE);

   // second bar chart
   // bottom axis must be there but must not be visible
   bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   bottomAxis.setVisible(false);

   XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
   rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);
   rightAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

   // set correct cross axis
   bottomAxis.crossAxis(rightAxis);
   rightAxis.crossAxis(bottomAxis);

   data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
   bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
   bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);
   
   // additional pad series - takes space at left side for secondary axis
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, pad);
   series.setTitle("pad", null);
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, pad);
   series.setTitle("pad", null);
   series = data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData2);
   series.setTitle("Series 2", null);
 
   chart.plot(data);
   
   // set bar colors
   solidFillSeries(data, 2, PresetColor.RED);
   
   // set legend 
   XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
   legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);
   // set legend entries for pad series deleted
   XDDFLegendEntry legendEntry = getOrAddLegendEntry(legend, 2);
   legendEntry.setDelete(true);
   legendEntry = getOrAddLegendEntry(legend, 3);
   legendEntry.setDelete(true);
   legendEntry = getOrAddLegendEntry(legend, 4);
   legendEntry.setDelete(true);

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelXDDFChart.xlsx")) {
    document.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }
 
 private static XDDFLegendEntry getOrAddLegendEntry(XDDFChartLegend legend, long index) {
  XDDFLegendEntry legendEntry = null;
  for (XDDFLegendEntry storedLegendEntry : legend.getEntries()) {
   if (storedLegendEntry.getIndex() == index) {
    legendEntry = storedLegendEntry;
    break;
   }   
  }
  if (legendEntry == null) {
   legendEntry = legend.addEntry();
   legendEntry.setIndex(index); 
  }
  return legendEntry;
 } 
 
 private static void solidFillSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
  XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries(index);
  XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
  if (properties == null) {
   properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
  }
  properties.setFillProperties(fill);
  series.setShapeProperties(properties);
 }
}
```

Comment: I have one more question. With your help, we succeeded in creating the left axis and the right axis. Two data referring to the left axis and one data referring to the right axis. In other words How can I add one more data to the left axis?

Comment: @배효성: In my example the first bar chart uses the left axis. So do add one more series to the `data` of the first bar chart.

Comment: I added another column to the data on the first bar chart. The charts are overlapping.

Comment: @배효성: If you have more than one series in one of the bar chart, you need more pad series in the other bar chart which uses the other axis. See my supplements in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks to you, I solved the problem.